How to scrape table into dataframe with selenium / requests / beautifulsoup?
My objective is that for website https://data.eastmoney.com/executive/000001.html, when you scroll down you will find a big table

and I want to turn it into a DataFrame in Python. Is BeautifulSoup enough to do so or do I have to use Selenium?
Some people on Stack Overflow said that BeautifulSoup cannot crawl table data from the Internet, so I tried Selenium and here is the code:
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://data.eastmoney.com/executive/000001.html')
table_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table")
item_element = table_element.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[2]/td[3]")
item_text = item_element.text
df = pd.DataFrame([item_text], columns=["Item"])
print(df)
driver.quit()

and here is the outcome:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver': 'chromedriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/entry.py", line 379, in _run
    engine.start()
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/engine.py", line 231, in start
    self._dispatcher.start()
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/dispatcher.py", line 280, in start
    self._run_loop()
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/dispatcher.py", line 240, in _run_loop
    self._loop.run()
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/loop/loop.py", line 107, in run
    self._handle_queue()
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/loop/loop.py", line 153, in _handle_queue
    message.callback(**message.callback_data)
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/mds/market_data_subscriber.py", line 228, in broadcast
    consumer.send(market_data)
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/mds/market_data_consumer_manager.py", line 59, in    consumer_gen
    msg_callback()
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/mds/market_data_consumer_manager.py", line 52, in   msg_callback
    callback(market_data)
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/mds/market_data_consumer_manager.py", line 122, in  wrapper
    result = callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/strategy.py", line 474, in _wrapper
    self._context.current_dt
  File "/tmp/strategy/user_code.py", line 85, in handle_data
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in     PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Basically it says "Chromedriver.exe needs to be in PATH". The problem is I am using an online backtest platform called JoinQuant (www.joinquant.com) and all the Python files such as File "selenium/webdriver/common/service.py" are not local - they are not on my computer's disk drive. So that's something complicated with Selenium - Do I have to use Selenium to crawl data like this from the Internet and turn it into DataFrame in Python? Or can I use something else like BeautifulSoup? For BeautifulSoup, as least it does not have the "drive needs to be in PATH" problem.
For BeautifulSoup, here's what I tried:
# Web Crawler
# Sent HTTP Request to get Internet content
url = 'https://data.eastmoney.com/executive/000001.html'
response = requests.get(url)
html_content = response.text

# Check if the request is successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Use BeautifulSoup to Analyze Internet information and get the table
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find_all('table')
    # Acquire the rows and columns of the table
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    data = []
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        row_data = []
        for col in cols:
            row_data.append(col.text.strip())
        data.append(row_data)
else:
    print("Failed to Retrieve the Webpage.")

# Set up DataFrame
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Print DataFrame
print(dataframe)

and here's the output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/entry.py", line 379, in _run
    engine.start()
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/engine.py", line 231, in start
    self._dispatcher.start()
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/dispatcher.py", line 280, in start
    self._run_loop()
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/dispatcher.py", line 240, in _run_loop
    self._loop.run()
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/loop/loop.py", line 107, in run
    self._handle_queue()
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/loop/loop.py", line 153, in _handle_queue
    message.callback(**message.callback_data)
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/mds/market_data_subscriber.py", line 228, in broadcast
    consumer.send(market_data)
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/mds/market_data_consumer_manager.py", line 59, in   consumer_gen
    msg_callback()
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/mds/market_data_consumer_manager.py", line 52, in  msg_callback
    callback(market_data)
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/mds/market_data_consumer_manager.py", line 122, in  wrapper
    result = callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/strategy.py", line 474, in _wrapper
    self._context.current_dt
  File "/tmp/strategy/user_code.py", line 114, in handle_data
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
  File "bs4/element.py", line 1884, in __getattr__
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a   single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of   items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

But if you change
table = soup.find_all('table')

into
table = soup.find('table')

Here's the outcome:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/entry.py", line 379, in _run
    engine.start()
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/engine.py", line 231, in start
    self._dispatcher.start()
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/dispatcher.py", line 280, in start
    self._run_loop()
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/dispatcher.py", line 240, in _run_loop
    self._loop.run()
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/loop/loop.py", line 107, in run
    self._handle_queue()
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/loop/loop.py", line 153, in _handle_queue
    message.callback(**message.callback_data)
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/mds/market_data_subscriber.py", line 228, in broadcast
    consumer.send(market_data)
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/mds/market_data_consumer_manager.py", line 59, in   consumer_gen
    msg_callback()
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/mds/market_data_consumer_manager.py", line 52, in msg_callback
    callback(market_data)
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/mds/market_data_consumer_manager.py", line 122, in wrapper
    result = callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/jqcore/jqboson/jqboson/core/strategy.py", line 474, in _wrapper
    self._context.current_dt
  File "/tmp/strategy/user_code.py", line 114, in handle_data
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

So to sum all up, which one should I use? Selenium or BeautifulSoup? Or even something else? And how should I tackle this issue?

No need to use selenium or beautifulsoup, in my opinion the easiest/directest way is to use the API through which the data is pulled.
How to know if content is loaded / rendered dynamically in this case?
First indicator, call up the website as a human in the browser and notice that a loading animation / delay appears for the area. Second indicator, the content is not included in the static response to the request. You can now use the browser's developer tools to look at the XHR Requests tab to see which data is being loaded from which resources. -> http://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network
If there is an api use it else go with selenium.
Url:
https://datacenter-web.eastmoney.com/api/data/v1/get

Parameters:
reportName: RPT_EXECUTIVE_HOLD_DETAILS
columns: ALL
filter: (SECURITY_CODE="000001")
pageNumber: 1
pageSize: 100 #increase this to avoid paging

Example
import requests
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(
    requests.get('https://datacenter-web.eastmoney.com/api/data/v1/get?reportName=RPT_EXECUTIVE_HOLD_DETAILS&columns=ALL&filter=(SECURITY_CODE%3D%22000001%22)&pageNumber=1&pageSize=30')\
        .json().get('result').get('data')
)





SECURITY_CODE
DERIVE_SECURITY_CODE
SECURITY_NAME
CHANGE_DATE
PERSON_NAME
CHANGE_SHARES
AVERAGE_PRICE
CHANGE_AMOUNT
CHANGE_REASON
CHANGE_RATIO
CHANGE_AFTER_HOLDNUM
HOLD_TYPE
DSE_PERSON_NAME
POSITION_NAME
PERSON_DSE_RELATION
ORG_CODE
GGEID
BEGIN_HOLD_NUM
END_HOLD_NUM




0
000001
000001.SZ
平安银行
2021-09-06 00:00:00
谢永林
26700
18.01
480867
竞价交易
0.0001
26700
A股
谢永林
董事
本人
10004085
173000004782302008
nan
26700


1
000001
000001.SZ
平安银行
2021-09-06 00:00:00
项有志
4000
18.46
73840
竞价交易
0.0001
26000
A股
项有志
董事,副行长,首席财务官
本人
10004085
173000004782302010
nan
26000


...





















32
000001
000001.SZ
平安银行
2009-08-19 00:00:00
刘巧莉
46200
21.04
972048
竞价交易
0.0015
nan
A股
马黎民
监事
配偶
10004085
140000000281406241
nan
nan


33
000001
000001.SZ
平安银行
2007-07-09 00:00:00
王魁芝
1600
27.9
44640
二级市场买卖
0.0001
7581
A股
王魁芝
监事
本人
10004085
173000001049726006
5981
7581




https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78573329/trading-program-got-stuck-whether-it-is-because-of-while-loop-or-something-else/78573429#78573429 How about this following question please?

The main problem that I see is that you are using a really old version of Selenium and you haven't specified the path to Chromedriver (and it's not in PATH) so it can't find it. If you update to the newest Selenium (at least 4.6), they've added a built in browser manager, SeleniumManager, that will take care of downloading and configuring whatever driver you need.
If you do go this route, once you upgrade Selenium you will see that .find_element_by_*(), e.g. .find_element_by_xpath(), no longer work. You will need to change them to the new syntax,
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//table")

For your Beautiful Soup error... I'm not experienced with it but from looking at the stack trace and error messages, I think the issue is here on these lines
table = soup.find_all('table')
rows = table.find_all('tr')

table is a collection and you did .find_all() on that collection, which doesn't work. If you change .find_all('table') to .find('table'), it should work. Updated code below,
table = soup.find('table')
rows = table.find_all('tr')


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78573329/trading-program-got-stuck-whether-it-is-because-of-while-loop-or-something-else/78573429#78573429 How about this following question please?
